# Log a Call subject pick-list different for account than contact

Tags: tasks, page-layout

I'm having a bit of a problem configuring the subject picklist for the "log a call" publisher action.

I have made some changes to the subject pick-list under

Setup>Customise>Task Fields>

This is a change in the order (to "Phone Call","Regular Visit", etc.) and updating "Call" to "Phone Call".

In Salesforce1 this update is apparent when I "log a call" from my contacts:
[image: Contact works]

When I attempt to "log a call" from an account the list has not been updated:

[image: Account Not Working]

Can anyone tell me where I can resolve this - I can't see where to deal with the different appearances.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the account page layout was using the standard "Mobile smart actions" Log a call.

When I removed that and selected Log a Call individually from the publisher actions, it married up with the contact one in respect of layout and customisation.

Ironically I received an email from Salesforce referring to the "Mobile smart action upgrade to publisher actions" this morning (a week too late for me!).

Part of this entailed:

> • If you wish to take advantage of publisher actions you will need to
>   complete the necessary steps to customize or create desired actions.
>   For example, you can use the same individual actions for Create Task,
>   New Event, New Note, and Log-a-Call, that you may have used as part of
>   the mobile smart actions collection. We encourage you to use
>   individual actions, as they offer the advantage of customizing layouts
>   to present users with only the most relevant fields. For a detailed
>   guide to working with publisher actions, please reference this admin
>   guide:
>   https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce1admin.meta/salesforce1admin/actions_creating.htm
>   (Available in English only).

This points to the answer to my question - selecting the publisher actions individually.